# Replacing a double digit number gives me an output as if its two numbers (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, integer

So I've got a program that converts numbers to letters but when I do a double digit number it acts like both the digits are different numbers.

code:

```
    decrypt = input()
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(1)), "a")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(2)), "b")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(3)), "c")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(4)), "d")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(5)), "e")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(6)), "f")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(7)), "g")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(8)), "h")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(9)), "i")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(10)), "j")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(11)), "k")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(12)), "l")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(13)), "m")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(14)), "n")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(15)), "o")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(16)), "p")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(17)), "q")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(18)), "r")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(19)), "s")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(20)), "t")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(21)), "u")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(22)), "v")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(23)), "w")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(24)), "x")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(25)), "y")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(26)), "z")
    decrypt = decrypt.replace((str(27)), "0")
    
    print("")
    print(decrypt)
```

So if i were to input 15, instead of giving me "o", it will give me "ae"
How do I make it so that it works with double digit numbers

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of your replacements.  In the current version, you do all of the single-digit occurrences first, which leaves *no* remaining digits for the later letters.  Start with str(27) and work down to 0.

Note that this will work more smoothly if you use a translation table (dict) instead.  You can easily look up how to do that.

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked. Also thanks for the suggestion